# Why does a simple pagination tag result in an error in Material UI?

Tags: next.js, material-ui, pagination

I am trying to add pagination using Joy/Material UI.  I find that adding even a simple  tag results in an error.

I am using Nextjs.

I have this code:

```
import Layout from "../components/Layout";

import Pagination from "@mui/material/Pagination";

export default function Blah() {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <Pagination count={10} color="primary" />
    </Layout >
  );
}
```

And displaying this simple page give me this:

```
Server Error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'focus')

This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.
Call Stack
PaginationItemPage.theme.theme
file:///workspace/NickBlog/node_modules/@mui/material/node/PaginationItem/PaginationItem.js (107:59)
transformedStyleArg
file:///workspace/NickBlog/node_modules/@mui/system/createStyled.js (199:40)
handleInterpolation
```

Happy to provide more information if needed.

What am I missing and/or doing wrong?

Comment: It appears that it is looking for a `theme.palette.action.focus` value from your theme.   Are you using a custom theme?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in the mixing of JoyUI and MaterialUI.

This page: https://mui.com/joy-ui/guides/using-joy-ui-and-material-ui-together/

The specific section is this one: https://mui.com/joy-ui/guides/using-joy-ui-and-material-ui-together/#set-up-the-providers

It explains what to do to make the CSSProviders line up and thus the themes sort themselves out.